# ¿Se están recibiendo y calculando correctamente los parámetros en este proyecto?

Tags: java, java-swing, poo

La clase procedimientos tiene como proceso este método:

```
public void LeerVotosCandidato1(String d1, String d2, String d3, String    d4, String d5)
{
    int D1, D2, D3, D4, D5;

    D1 = Integer.parseInt(d1);
    D2 = Integer.parseInt(d2);
    D3 = Integer.parseInt(d3);
    D4 = Integer.parseInt(d4);
    D5 = Integer.parseInt(d5);

    TVC1 = (D1 + D2 + D3 + D4 + D5);
}
```

Y este método recibe mediante el evento del botón del formulario así:

```
    Clase_FrmVotos Objeto = new Clase_FrmVotos();
    Objeto.LeerVotosCandidato1(lblC1D1.getText(), lblC1D2.getText(), lblC1D3.getText(), lblC1D4.getText(), lblC1D5.getText());
    btnVotarC1.setEnabled(false);
    }
```

Posteriormente esto se realiza con 5 Metodos LeerVotosCandidatos bajo la misma estrctura.
Adjuntaré imagen para mejor entendimiento
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora bien, posteriormente a recibir y calcular los datos e estos 4 métodos, se determinan los porcentajes de participación de la siguiente forma:

```
    public void CalcularPorcentajes()
{
    double TotalVotantes;

    TotalVotantes = (TVC1 + TVC2 + TVC3 + TVC4);

    PC1 = ((TVC1 * 100) / TotalVotantes);
    PC2 = ((TVC2 * 100) / TotalVotantes);
    PC3 = ((TVC3 * 100) / TotalVotantes);
    PC4 = ((TVC4 * 100) / TotalVotantes);
}
```

Y luego de esto se determina si hay o no ganador electoral bajo este método:

```
    public void DeterminarGanador()
{
    double Vector[] = new double[4];
       Vector[0] = PC1;
       Vector[1] = PC2;
       Vector[2] = PC3;
       Vector[3] = PC4;

    if (PC1 > 50 | PC2 > 50 | PC3 > 50 | PC4>50)
    {
       for (int i = 4; i<0; i = i -1)
       {
           if (Vector[i] > 50)
           {
               Ganador = "Candidato: " + Vector[i];  
           }
       }         
    }
    else
    {
        int L = 0; 
        double A;
        for (int i = 4; i<0; i = i -1)
        {
            if (Vector[i]<Vector[L])
            {
                A = Vector[i];
                Vector[i] = Vector[L];
                Vector[L] = A;
                L = L + 1;
            }

        }
        SegundaVuelta1 = "Candidato: " + Vector[1];
        SegundaVuelta2 = "Candidato: " + Vector[2];
    }
}
```

Una vez realizado todos los cálculos vienen los métodos de impresiones:

```
   public String RetornarPC1()
{
    String PorC1;
    PorC1 = String.valueOf(PC1);
    return PorC1;
}

public String RetornarPC2()
{
    String PorC2;
    PorC2 = String.valueOf(PC2);
    return PorC2;
}

public String RetornarPC3()
{
    String PorC3;
    PorC3 = String.valueOf(PC3);
    return PorC3;
}

public String RetornarPC4()
{
    String PorC4;
    PorC4 = String.valueOf(PC4);
    return PorC4;  
}

public String ObtenerGanador()
{
    return Ganador;
}

public String ObetenerSegundaVuelta1()
{
    return SegundaVuelta1;
}

public String ObtenerSegundaVuelta2()
{
    return SegundaVuelta2;
}
```

El problema es el siguiente: Si se ingresan los datos de la siguiente forma o la que sea (ya se ha intentado), siempre muestra el mismo resultado, y anteriormente todas las respuestas daban cero.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Además de que la tabla no imprime la fabulación de los votos.
Si sobra el interés y hace falta información: Ajunto link de descarga del proyecto:
[introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8ePnBPsRVPeOWluZWlWSjE0aGM/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

Para calcular los totales por candidato has esto:

```
   public int leerVotosCandidato(String d1, String d2, String d3, String d4, String d5)
   {
        int resultado = Integer.parseInt(d1) + Integer.parseInt(d2) + Integer.parseInt(d3) 
        + Integer.parseInt(d4) + Integer.parseInt(d5);    
        return resultado;
   }
```

Ahora, para cada candidato, lo único que tienes que hace es pasarle sus respectivos valores:

```
TC1 =  leerVotosCandidatos(lblC1D1.getText(), lblC1D2.getText(), lblC1D3.getText(), 
           lblC1D4.getText(), lblC1D5.getText());
TC2 =  leerVotosCandidatos(lblC2D1.getText(), lblC2D2.getText(), lblC2D3.getText(), 
               lblC2D4.getText(), lblC2D5.getText());
TC3 =  leerVotosCandidatos(lblC3D1.getText(), lblC3D2.getText(), lblC3D3.getText(), 
               lblC3D4.getText(), lblC3D5.getText());
TC4 =  leerVotosCandidatos(lblC4D1.getText(), lblC4D2.getText(), lblC4D3.getText(), 
               lblC4D4.getText(), lblC4D5.getText());
```

Porque de la forma que estás encarando tu metodo void LeerVotosCandidato1, tendráis que tener un método para cada candidato, en cambio de la forma que te planteo, utilizas un solo método para los 4 y solo varía los parámetros pasados para cada candidato.